# Fullscreen in manifest.json is not really fullscreen in Android?

Tags: android, google-chrome, fullscreen, progressive-web-apps

I want a PWA to run in fullscreen mode so I have this in `manifest.json`:

```
"display": "fullscreen",
```

It is nearly fullscreen (when I install the PWA on my Android phone), but it looks like this (at the top):

[image]

The address bar is gone. Good. But the blue part at the top should not be there. And it disappears when I call:

```
    document.documentElement.requestFullscreen();
```

However I can do that only on a user initiated request, as far as I know. And calling it shows a notice ("Drag from top ... to exit fullscreen") which is rather annoying in this PWA.

Am I missing something? Can I get rid of the blue bar at the top?

---

EDIT: Submitted bug: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=973006

Comment: When using the Lighthouse tool you are passing all PWA checks with no errors?
Also, this happens on someone else's Android phone too?

Comment: Don't you mean to use `"display": "standalone"`?

Comment: @Mathias Yes, I get no errors in Lighthouse.

Comment: @TmKVU No, `standalone` is fallback for `fullscreen`. And I think it displays the address bar?

Comment: @Mathias I will check on another phone later. But this is with clean Android ver 8 (Motorola Moto G5).

Comment: If you have a URL you can share I can try on my Android. Your app should go up to but not over the android bar. That will ALWAYS be there. Is your app the white, or does it also include the purple? When I first looked I guessed the white.

Comment: Also, while the app is closed if you drag the icon up from your home screen, do you get a Remove AND Uninstall option? I'm checking to see if your device thinks it is an installed WebApk.